# "This value should not be blank" error in Mailchimp email service

Tags: javascript, api, email, http-status-code-400

I'm now taking Angela's Bootcamp about web development and when I was coding the JavaScript File using the service from Mailchimp, I ran into some error in the picture:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y1LYE.jpg)

I just can't understand what this error means. And I can sure my api key, list ID and the user name are all true. The value of "email_adress" is consistent with the input name "email" in the HTML file. And I have already input the email adress in the page, but after I submitted, it shows this error. I just follow the video so I don't know where is the problem. Here I paste my code.

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const request = require("request");
const https = require("https");
//require the newly installed modules inside app.js
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));

app.use(express.static("public"));

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
})

app.post("/", function(req, res) {
  const firstName = req.body.firstName;
  const lastName = req.body.lastName;
  const email = req.body.email;

  const data = {
    members: [{
      email_address: email,
      status: "subscribed",
      merge_fields: {
        FNAME: firstName,
        LNAME: lastName
      }
    }]
  }


  const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
  const url = "https://us10.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/bdfa0011db/members"
  //the number after "us" should be replaced by your last number of api key
  //the string afrer "lists" is your list ID
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    auth: "Aria0325:16fb2bcb22d07b6cdaebcf505be978dd-us10"
  };


  const request = https.request(url, options, function(response) {
    response.on("data", function(data) {
      console.log(JSON.parse(data))
    })
  });

  request.write(jsonData);
  request.end();

})

app.listen(3000, function() {
  console.log("Server is running on port 3000");
})

//api key
//16fb2bcb22d07b6cdaebcf505be978dd-us10

//list id
//bdfa0011db
```

HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="Mark Otto, Jacob Thornton, and Bootstrap contributors">
    <meta name="generator" content="Hugo 0.101.0">
    <title>Newsletter Signup</title>

    <link rel="canonical" href="https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/sign-in/">





<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-gH2yIJqKdNHPEq0n4Mqa/HGKIhSkIHeL5AyhkYV8i59U5AR6csBvApHHNl/vI1Bx" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Favicons -->
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/docs/5.2/assets/img/favicons/apple-touch-icon.png" sizes="180x180">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.2/assets/img/favicons/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" type="image/png">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.2/assets/img/favicons/favicon-16x16.png" sizes="16x16" type="image/png">
<link rel="manifest" href="/docs/5.2/assets/img/favicons/manifest.json">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/docs/5.2/assets/img/favicons/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#712cf9">
<link rel="icon" href="/docs/5.2/assets/img/favicons/favicon.ico">
<meta name="theme-color" content="#712cf9">


    <style>
      .bd-placeholder-img {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
        text-anchor: middle;
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
      }

      @media (min-width: 768px) {
        .bd-placeholder-img-lg {
          font-size: 3.5rem;
        }
      }

      .b-example-divider {
        height: 3rem;
        background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
        border: solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
        border-width: 1px 0;
        box-shadow: inset 0 .5em 1.5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .1), inset 0 .125em .5em rgba(0, 0, 0, .15);
      }

      .b-example-vr {
        flex-shrink: 0;
        width: 1.5rem;
        height: 100vh;
      }

      .bi {
        vertical-align: -.125em;
        fill: currentColor;
      }

      .nav-scroller {
        position: relative;
        z-index: 2;
        height: 2.75rem;
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }

      .nav-scroller .nav {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: nowrap;
        padding-bottom: 1rem;
        margin-top: -1px;
        overflow-x: auto;
        text-align: center;
        white-space: nowrap;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
      }
    </style>


    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body class="text-center">

<main class="form-signin w-100 m-auto">
  <form action="/" method="post">
    <img class="mb-4" src="images/SodaCup.png" alt="" width="150" height="150">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-3 fw-normal">Sign up to my Newsletter!</h1>

    <input type="text" class="form-control top"  placeholder="First Name" name="firstName">
    <input type="text" class="form-control middle"  placeholder="Last Name" name="lastName">
    <input type="email" class="form-control bottom" placeholder="Email" name="email">


    <button class="w-100 btn btn-lg btn-primary" type="submit">Sign me up!</button>
    <p class="mt-5 mb-3 text-muted">&copy; Aria</p>
  </form>
</main>



  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: the `this` that can't be blank is the field `email_address` - your code isn't sending `email_address` to that API

Comment: You can see my edited version now. I added more details.